# checking if the user exits in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

petfriend has an attribute called `username` which is common in both the `Petfriend` and `User`.
i would like to know how can I check if the `Petfriend` `username` exists in the `User` model when creating the `Petfriend`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by adding callback in Petfriend model like:-

```
Class Petfriend
    before_create :username_exists_in_user

    private
    def username_exists_in_user
        is_username_exists = User.pluck(:username).include?(slef.username)
        if is_username_exists
            self.errors.add(:base, "#{self.username} is exists")
            return false
        end
    end
end
```